# What do I need to get started with developing medium format film?

Tags: film, developing, medium-format

Only have experience with digital cameras, camcorders and DSLRs. What process is required to fully develop photos shot on a medium format film camera? It sounds like only hardcore photographers should get one since you require a physical darkroom to dip the photos in liquid. Is it difficult? Is the process substantially different than developing 35mm film?

Can someone provide a step-by-step, plus equipment and what sort of overhead in maintenance you're looking at versus digital cameras, for developing film photos to the stage of being scanned in as digital images?

Comment: The difficulty depends on whether you are shooting B&W or Color.  But the level difficulty is basically the same for 35mm or Medium Format or Large Format.  As for me, when I shoot film I just send it to be developed at a local lab.  I haven't developed my own film in over 20 years, so I can't attest to what it takes for a home lab.

Comment: for color photos

Comment: You seem to mix together film development and printing, which are two quite different steps towards a paper photography. Developing the film (also colour film) can be done relatively easily outside a dark room with inexpensive equipment. If you want to make paper prints, you need a room which can at least temporarily be used as a dark room. A bath room is usually good enough if you are able to completely cover up all light sources (windows, door frames and all other things letting light in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a bathroom or a changing bag for a darkroom for years; you don't need more than that for an appropriate space.  You'll need to invest in both processing chemicals (i.e., Developer, Stop Bath, Fixer, Photo-Flo) and developing equipment (changing bag, film clips, developing tank, developing reel, film squeegee, thermometer, measuring beaker, 4 opaque gallon jugs, funnel). An excellent source of these chemicals and items of equipment is [www.freestylephoto.biz](http://www.freestylephoto.biz).  You may also wish to browse through [www.darkroomcookbook.com/phpbb/](http://www.darkroomcookbook.com/phpbb/) for any further questions on the process.  Finally, you will need to either purchase a film scanner or send your negatives to an outside vendor for scanning.